# how to find the maximum size of ostream class in c++

Tags: c++

I am assigning `std::ostream *pout_ = output_.get();`
where `output_` is `scoped_ptr<std::stringstream> output_;`

after assigning i am filling `*pout_ <<"large strings";` appx 1172528 characters.

But after some extent i am not able to insert charcters inside `*pout_`. I tried surfing on the net whats the maximum size of this class but couldn't find.

Someone please tell how much characters maximum i can store in `*pout_`. Is there any function which can tell me the maximum size of this class??

Comment: Streams are not containers; they do not _store_ anything. They are, instead, _flows of data_. (You mean to talk about the underlying buffer, I am sure!)

Comment: 1172528 sure was an exact approximate ;)

Comment: thanks for correcting me..then if the data flows through them then is there any restriction about how much data can flow or how much undeline buffer can store??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible causes for output to an `ostream` to fail.
The most obvious is that the underlying supporting media (memory, in the
case of an `std::ostringstream`) is full.  Another is that you've
reached some internal limit: a lot of systems have (or had) file size
limits which would hit you long before the disk was full, and some
systems have had similar constraints on single objects in memory (and
the `std::stringbuf` class typically keeps its data in a single object).
(There's also the possiblity of a hardware error, but if this occurs
with `std::stringbuf`, i.e. a memory error, the hardware probably won't 
detect it.)

All of these mean that there is no hard limit as to how much you can
write to a stream, string or otherwise.  It all depends, and one time,
you might succeed writing 2 GB, and the next fail after 1 MB or less.
Practically speaking, in most cases, you should be aware of the fact
that writes can fail, test the results (after a final flush) and be
prepared to do something reasonable if they do.

In the specific case of string streams, of course, about the only
failure you're likely to be able to detect is out of memory.  (An
`ostream` does **not** propagate an exception from the `streambuf`; it
sets the `badbit` when one occurs, and if exceptions have been activated
for `badbit`, it will throw its own exception, not rethrow the original
one.  Which means that an `std::bad_alloc` will not propagate out.)
A lot of applications don't handle out of memory, and should logically
have set the new handler to abort.  If you've set the new handler to
abort, then you can probably forego such error checking on string
outputs.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your compiler, platform etc. It also depends on the manner in which you write stuff to the `stringstream` (since it may need to reallocate memory for its buffer, potentially causing memory fragmentation and therefore under-utilisation).

The only practical way to get an idea of the limit is by conducting realistic experiments in your target environment. Even then, you should only use the results of such experiments as a rough guide.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the dependencies. I run the code found in [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166826/stringstream-overflow-at-4gb) and found that it crashes at 3GB on my Mac, because of the way it uses reallocate.

Answer (score 1):

A stringstream stores the data in a memory buffer. It will grow the buffer as needed, as long as it can.

You can continue to write to it until you run out of memory. There is not fixed limit.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a huge number of factors, such as

- what load addresses are chosen for the shared objects you used
- how much memory the rest of your program uses
- how badly fragmented your address space has become

That's why you couldn't find any documented limit on the web.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on OS/Compiler. See my answer here about the maximum values for  Windows, CentOS, and Ubuntu: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77612716/1244696