# stringstream overflow at 4GB

Tags: c++, stl, overflow, stringstream

I'm having trouble getting beyond 4GB limitation for stringstream, even though it is running on a 64bit linux box with enough memory.

The test code below (revised after reading your comments) core dump after 4GB.

From the gdb trace, stringstream uses the default std::char_traits where int_type is set to 32bit int, rather than 64bit size_t. Any suggestion to work around?

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int narg, char** argv)
{
    string str;
    stringstream ss;
    const size_t GB = (size_t)pow(2, 30);

    str.resize(GB, '1');
    cerr << "1GB=" << str.size()
             << ", string::max_size=" << str.max_size()/GB << "GB"
             << ", sizeof(int)=" << sizeof(int)
             << ", sizeof(int64_t)=" << sizeof(int64_t)
             << ", sizeof(size_t)=" << sizeof(size_t)
             << endl;
    string().swap(str);

    str.resize(6*GB, '6');
    cerr << "str.size()=" << (str.size() / GB) << "GB allocated successfully"
            << ", ended with " << str.substr(str.size()-5, 5) << endl;
    string().swap(str);

    str.resize(GB/4, 'Q');
    cerr << "writing to stringstream..." << std::flush;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
        ss << str << endl;
        cerr << double(ss.str().size())/GB << "GB " << std::flush;
    }
    cerr << endl;
    exit(0);
}
```

The output is:

```
1GB=1073741824, string::max_size=4294967295GB, sizeof(int)=4, sizeof(int64_t)=8, sizeof(size_t)=8
str.size()=6GB allocated successfully, ended with 66666
writing to stringstream...0.25GB 0.5GB 0.75GB 1GB 1.25GB 1.5GB 1.75GB 2GB 2.25GB 2.5GB 2.75GB 3GB 3.25GB 3.5GB 3.75GB Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The gdb stack trace is:

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x00002aaaaad5e0c1 in std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00002aaaaad62cbd in std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00002aaaaad5657d in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x000000000040112b in main ()
```

The binary seems to be 64bits.

```
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

Nick, good point on checking the preprocessor output. Somehow std::char_straits overwrites __gnu_cxx::char_straits, and redefines int_type to be int, rather than unsigned long as in __gnu_cxx::char_straits. This is very surprising!

```
namespace __gnu_cxx
{
# 61 "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/char_traits.h" 3
  template <class _CharT>
    struct _Char_types
    {
      typedef unsigned long int_type;
      typedef std::streampos pos_type;
      typedef std::streamoff off_type;
      typedef std::mbstate_t state_type;
    };
# 86 "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/char_traits.h" 3
  template<typename _CharT>
    struct char_traits
    {
      typedef _CharT char_type;
      typedef typename _Char_types<_CharT>::int_type int_type;
      typedef typename _Char_types<_CharT>::pos_type pos_type;
      typedef typename _Char_types<_CharT>::off_type off_type;
      typedef typename _Char_types<_CharT>::state_type state_type;
              ....
               };

namespace std
{
# 224 "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/char_traits.h" 3
  template<class _CharT>
    struct char_traits : public __gnu_cxx::char_traits<_CharT>
    { };



  template<>
    struct char_traits<char>
    {
      typedef char char_type;
      typedef int int_type;
      typedef streampos pos_type;
      typedef streamoff off_type;
      typedef mbstate_t state_type;
              ...
              };
```

EDIT:  below from the STL website http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/char_traits/ where char_traits specialization uses int.

```
typedef INT_T int_type; 
Where INT_T is a type that can represent all the valid characters representable by a    char_type plus an end-of-file value (eof) which is compatible with iostream class member functions.
For char_traits<char> this is int, and for char_traits<wchar_t> this is wint_t
```

Comment: Suggestion: build in 64 bit mode

Comment: I think your problem is the SO memory management. It can kill you application when the limit of memory per applicaion is reached.

Comment: Looking at the gcc implementation it seems to do reasonable things. Did you verify that you can allocate a memory block bigger than 4GB, e.g. with 8GB? Internally, gcc's string buffer seems to double the size of its buffer each time it needs to increase the buffer.
Also, a bit of nitpicking (this isn't your problem): at the end of the code it should be `delete[] GB` since you had allocated an array object.

Comment: What about string::reserve(WHAT_YOU_WANT) and string::apend(GB)?

Comment: @Ping C, among programmers (as opposed to hard disk manufacturers), GB is usually defined as `2^30` bytes rather than your `10^9`. Your program crashes at ~3.9581GB, which strongly suggests 32-bit addressing.

Comment: Do you have any `ulimit` set?

Comment: @The cplusplus.com is NOT the STL website, and cplusplus.com is _wrong_ here.

Comment: As you've already [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166826/stringstream-overflow-at-4gb#comment16341283_12170732) this is likely to be some headers/library issue. Your code works on my CentOS 6.5, gcc 4.9.4, so "use newer gcc" might be the answer.

However, the most recent MSVS (15.4.0 preview 1) is [still not able](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a2bf0057-6d72-4b22-b29f-76c2c2afca3c/maximum-length-of-stdstringstream-on-x64?forum=vclanguage) to run it: `writing to stringstream...0.25GB 0.5GB 0.75GB 1GB 1.25GB 1.5GB 1.75GB 2GB 2GB 2GB ...`

Answer (score 1):

Can you post a preprocessed source file.

*Reference to `_Char_types` removed because it was misleading.*

I'm not sure the int_type is related, the specialisation for char does indeed use int for int_type.

int_type is a typedef to hold an individual character (i.e. at least one byte for ascii, higher for wchar_t). It is not used to store a range of characters (see std::streamoff below).

---

From your preprocessed output I suspect that std::streamoff could be the culprit. From the headers on my system:

```
# 90 "/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/postypes.h" 3
  typedef long streamoff;
```

std::streamoff is used in std::streampos which if defined incorrectly I think would lead to the stringstream calling the overflow function.

Have you checked that the correct headers are included?

```
# 61 "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/char_traits.h" 3
```

Is the following path:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/bits/char_traits.h
```

-nick

Comment: Yes, the path and streamoff match yours. STL std::char_traits specialization use int, as stated in their doc, which I suppose means int is used to address memory (as in overflow signature), and thus 4GB limitation. My current workaround (to convert string to ostream) is to use boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream ostream(back_inserter(str)). Curious of other options ...

Comment: @PingC.: Wonder what `sizeof(size_t)` is in PingC's program.